# How to display the count of dropdown items using selenium and python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver

I am trying to get all elements within a drop down and print the total count. Here's the code, which I have written for this.

```
import unittest
from selenium import  webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

class dropdown(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()


def test_selectmethod(self):
    driver=self.driver
    driver.get("http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='select-language']").click()

    dropdown=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='select-language']"))
    print str(len(dropdown)+ "products found"

    for i in dropdown:
        print(i.text)



def tearDown(self):
self.driver.close()
```

However, this throws error while printing `str(len(dropdown)`.

Comment: I am getting error in these line only     print str(len(dropdown)+ "products found"

Comment: This code `dropdown=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='select-language']"))` should return a select element. You have to get all the options element within select element using `findelements` (in C#, use equivalent for python).

Comment: so instead of find element have to use find elements right?

Comment: but still facing the same problem

Comment: When you use FindElements, it return a `ReadOnlyCollection<IwebElements>`, on which you should be able to use `.count()` to get the count.  If it returns zero, then xpath may have to modify to get correct value.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? It's always useful to look at the error message and the traceback. You'll often understand what the problem is from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `str(len(dropdown.options))`.

Answer (score 0):

To display the count of dropdown items using selenium python you don't even have to identify the `<select>` tag and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/")
  count = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='select-language']//option"))))
  print(str(count) + " items found." )
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  3 items found.
  ```

---

But if you want to print the `<options>` within the `<select>` tag you have to identify the `<select>` tag and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/")
  count = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='select-language']//option"))))
  print(str(count) + " items found." )
  dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='select-language']"))
  print("Items are: " )
  for i in dropdown.options:
      print(i.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  3 items found.
  Items are: 
  English
  French
  German
  ```